# Are any senses of the word 'candidate' acceptable for attributive-noun usage?

Tags: meaning, neologisms, polysemes

I've just used 'candidate' attributively to mean '[worth considering as] a real possibility [for the purpose stated, or implied by context] (eg a candidate term or construction).

I've not been able to find a licensing of any attributive usage in AHDEL, Collins, M-W, RHK Webster's or Google Dictionary.

[YourDictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/candidate) merely lists variously sourced examples of the usage meaning 'relating to / worthy of a candidate':

> As soon as Jake Weller left, Cynthia questioned her husband about the
>   candidate filing papers Weller handed him.
>
> Dean pulled down the top on his Jeep and slowly drove uptown,
>   giving off what he hoped were candidate smiles and waves to the
>   locals, all of whom seemed to be walking the sun drenched street.

I *have* found one incidental example of the 'obviously should be at least considered as a possibility' sense within Wiktionary Talk:

> en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:Donald_Duck
>
> WT:CFI does not define
>   "attributive". If you have your own candidate definition of
>   "attributive" ...

But is such a usage acceptable?

Comment: I've certainly used it that way. But that doesn't mean much, coming from an uppity Yank ;) BTW, your second example (of the *sun drenched streets*) is using *candidate* a different way: *as or like a political candidate*: a big, bright, toothy smile.

Comment: Ngram suggests little usage of those expressions: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=candidate+smile%2Ccandidate+behaviour%2C+candidate+definition&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccandidate%20smile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccandidate%20behaviour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccandidate%20definition%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Dan Bron '/ worthy of' was how I put it. Most adjective definitions traditionally began 'of, like or pertaining to ...'

Comment: @Josh61 I'm against do-it-yourself in general, but this is one usage I hope becomes general. (At the moment, it seems to be a candidate usage.)

Comment: @Edwin, point taken, but it seems to me there's a qualitative and categorical difference between the *candidate smile* and *candidate definition*: the latter can be *chosen* (from among other competitors in the field), whereas the former cannot be chosen and *introduces to a third-party*.

Comment: That's really the basis of my question. I've defined the sense in 'candidate definition'; I'm asking about how generally accepted it is. I'll continue to use it as it's out there, usually unambiguous and clear in meaning, and very useful.

Comment: In genetics, you sometimes have *candidate genes*, multiple genes that might be coding for something you are interested in and thus also are worth to be considered for further research.

Comment: Thank you, skymninge. I'll continue to use 'candidate' attributively in the 'at least consider this as a possibility' sense. Candidate definition. Candidate answer. Candidate word. The fact that 'candidate' and the head noun are non-intersective is useful. A neologism has to be a {new[-ish]} word, but just as a red herring isn't a herring, a candidate word is not yet accurately describable as a word.

Comment: I don't see why anybody should bend over backwards trying to justify this usage while we have such excellent words as "potential," "prospective," etc.

Comment: I like the connotation (at least) of being _chosen_ which 'potential' doesn't carry. And 'prospective' has the sense 'likely [to occur]'. // A 'candidate solution' is a solution, not a possible one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary says that the noun can be used "in apposition" and gives the following two historical examples:

> 1735   Swift *Author upon Himself* in *Wks.* II. 347   Caress't by
>   Candidate Divines. 
> 1844   J. H. Stocqueler *Hand-bk. India* 297 A numerous supplementary class of candidate pupils.

I'm not completely sure, but I think these match the usage you are talking about.

Comment: Yes indeed. The OED terminology is perhaps unusual, but that's the usage. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my work I must frequently choose between competing *[candidate solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_solution)*. This appears to be an increasingly common ([according to Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=candidate%20solution&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccandidate%20solution%3B%2Cc0)) example of *candidate* used attributively.

Comment: Thank you, mike. If you link to the relevant Ngram/s, you may well get upvoted. I've obviated the rather perplexing downvote.